# Any minimally-instrusive way to add clickable object on all pages on any website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, frames

Is there a way to add floating clickable object (button / image), that then opens a web-form (such as a feedback or survey form), to every page of a website, be it static HTML or dynamic website (using PHP, Python, Ruby or such technologies) ?

Can it be done by just editing or adding an index.html, the main purpose being adding an invisible frame holding the javascript that then causes the floating clickable object, to be visible on every page -- either static HTML or dynamically generated, for as long as the viewer is on this website ?

Graphically explained:
[image]
So, I want to be able to show the floating clickable object in page rendered by index_1.php, prods.php, clients.php, contact.php, without having to editing any of those.

If there are examples of such techniques, such as in any opensource project, a pointer would be very useful.

The reason for such a question is to see if the feedback form, can be added for / on behalf of non-programmer website owners, who got the site developed by 3rd party, who are no longer maintaining it. And, be able to add the form, with minimal effort.

Comment: Do you have a layout template for all pages, or perhaps header/footer files? The JavaScript call can go in there. If the page structure is redundantly copied across all files, then unfortunately you'll need to edit them all. That's frustrating but not risky - just make sure you store everything in version control so you can revert any mistakes.

Comment: While still theoretical, I am looking at a solution where this "floating clickable object" insertion needs to happen on hundreds of websites of individuals and small businesses who got the site developed once and don't want to pay-for or themselves touch the website ever again. All they have is cPanel access. No documentation of how the website was developed. It could be all static (which would be the simplest case), or using CMSs like Drupal, Wordpress etc. or something more esoteric.

Comment: I'd be willing to say that a one-size-fits-all here would be impossible, unfortunately. To add JavaScript sensibly to a website, you need to understand its structure. Even with Wordpress, where a theme can be implemented in all manner of different ways, you need a programmer to make sense of it.

Comment: (That said, Wordpress adds some standard hooks that would allow you to do this. But you'd need to do something different for Drupal, and again for all the others).

Comment: Thanks @halfer - pretty much what I anticipated, but was still hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

No frames needed. You can put a JavaScript (or just plain HTML) in your site to create an `absolute` or `fixed` positioned element placed above all other elements.

I think you mean something like UserVoice, take a look at their widget:
https://www.uservoice.com/widget/

Comment: Thanks for answering. One of the key objectives is to avoid making extensive changes, and if possible limit the changes to a single file like index.html only and also work with sites that dynamically generate HTML. The idea of hidden frame was to see if I could have a static landing page with such a frame, which then "encompasses" all other usual content at that site, in the visible frame.

Comment: Well then use a JavaScript that creates the elements dynamically – the “change” this requires in the target pages is adding one simple line that refers to that script the usual way.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe and apologies for feeling dumb (my JS skills are very limited), but are you suggesting that a script started on the landing-page can dynamically insert reference to another javascript in all subsequent page's HTML ? The intention is really to not having to change anything except the initial landing page.

Comment: No, of course not (did not realize that you wanted to put it into the “landing page” only) – you would have to embed that script into every singe HTML page where it should run in.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I wish to achive, and edited the question by adding a graphic to clarify.